# "Open from clipboard" shortcut in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I often have a class or method reference in my clipboard. For example, when copying a reference from a failed unit test or from command line.

What is the most efficient way to navigate to this reference?

In eclipse, there is the `Open from clipboard` shortcut, which opens the reference. Is there anything comparable in IntelliJ Idea? From the [eclipse docs](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-navigate.htm):

> Tries to open the matching Java element in the editor if the clipboard
>   contains a single line. Otherwise it opens the contents in the Java
>   Stack Trace Console. Examples:
>
> - java.lang.String
> - String
> - String#getBytes
> - String.getBytes
> - java.lang.String.getBytes(String)
> - String.java:123
> - at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:1550)
> - java.lang.String.valueOf(char) line: 1456
> - currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 1):

**Navigate** | **Symbol…** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Mac).

(Paste the reference into the text field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate).